# The load() function cause redirect on delete button on datatable and laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I have Laravel 8 mix and I created datatable where the data are fetched with php script compatible with the blade template the table possesses add, and edit buttons which works well with Ajax, when it comes to the delete button It delete the first data and the snackbar with success message shown but after the load() excecuted and I want to delete another data, after clicking delete button no notification snackbar but the page change to json page with success message you can see on the code,the page come with message in this format so when i refresh the page manually I see the deleted data removed

```
{"message":"User deleted!!"}
```

How can I solve this problem, because when I remove that load() the deleted data remain on page until I manually refresh page, here button code:

```
<td class="action-btn">
    <form method="POST" class="delete-fm">
        @csrf
        @method("DELETE")
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$user->id}}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm bg-danger-light btn-rounded">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
</td>
```

my jquery ajax here:

```
$('.delete-fm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var id = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('users')}}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        encode: true,
    }).done( function (data) {
        
        if(data.success == false) {
            Snackbar.show({
                text: data.message,
                pos: 'top-right',
                actionTextColor: '#fff',
                backgroundColor: '#e2a03f'
            });
        }else{
            Snackbar.show({
                text: data.message,
                pos: 'top-right',
                actionTextColor: '#fff',
                backgroundColor: '#8dbf42'
            });
            $("#user-table").load(document.URL +  " #user-table > *" );
        }
    });
});
```

I want to delete user and show up notification even for second user and more at the same time with no page reload, I dont want to use yajra it is not compatible with my design

note the table filled by blade php and the jquery datatable is a plugin

```
//after inlitialize the table and head here the body 
<tbody>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2 class="table-avatar">
                    @if(!empty($user->avatar))
                    <span class="avatar avatar-sm mr-2">
                        <img class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="{{asset('storage/users/'.$user->avatar)}}" alt="product image">
                    </span>
                    @else
                    <p class="table-img-name">{{substr($user->name,0,1)}}</p>
                    @endif
                </h2>
            </td>
            <td>
            {{$user->name}}
            </td>
            <td>
            {{$user->email}}
            </td>
            <td class="action-btn">
              <a data-id="{{$user->id}}" data-name="{{$user->name}}" data-email="{{$user->email}}" class="btn btn-sm bg-success-light btn-rounded editbtn" id="edit-user" href="javascript:void(0)">
                 <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i>
              </a>
            </td
            <td class="action-btn">
             <form method="POST" class="delete-user-fm">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$user->id}}">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm bg-danger-light btn-rounded">
                <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: add the code which initially fills the table data

Comment: @shubham the code is already added